# How to pause AVAudioPlayer instead of finish the audio

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I have one strange requirement that i want my audio player to be paused when it will finish the audio. so i can backward the audio even if it will finish the play.

Any crazy idea on this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a pausedTime variable in your interface.

```
@interface

NSTimeInterval pausedTime;
AVAudioPlayer *avAudioPlayer;

@end
```

Then, in implementation section, you can ad these following methods to perform pause and resume function.

```
@implementation

-(void)pauseAudio
{
  pausedTime = avAudioPlayer.currentTime;
  [avAudioPlayer stop];
}

-(void)resumeAudioPlaying
{
  [avAudioPlayer playAtTime:pausedTime];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It **isn't pretty**, but you could use the AVAudioPlayerDelegate method to detect when the sound is done playing, then create a new player object with its seek position set to just be the end of the track and then pause it.

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWith....];

    if ([player prepareToPlay]) {
        [player playAtTime:player.duration - 1];
        [player pause];
    }
}
```